# SQL 2012 - Pivot and Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have summarised data in a table which is similar to this:

```
Customer Year Month No_trans spend  points
1        2015 1     30       400    10
1        2015 2     20       150    5
1        2015 3     10       500    15
2        2015 1     5        100    7
```

I would like to try and use Pivot/Unpivot to change to this, is it possible?

```
??????   Customer 2015_1 2015_2 2015_3  
No_trans 1        30     20     10               
Spend    1        400    150    500
Points   1        10     5      15
No_trans 2        5      0      0               
Spend    2        100    0      0
Points   2        7      0      0
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give more clarification what you want as result?

Comment: `2        2015 1     5        100    7` You should have values in `2015_1` column at desired result not `2015_3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL to transpose table:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
                STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT([Year], '_', [Month]))
                      FROM #tab
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     , 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
FORMATMESSAGE(
N'SELECT col_name, customer, %s
FROM (SELECT [year_month] = CONCAT([Year], ''_'', [Month]),
             Customer, No_Trans, spend, points
      FROM #tab) AS sub
UNPIVOT
(
    val FOR col_name  IN (No_trans, spend, points)
) AS unpvt
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR [year_month] IN (%s)
) AS pvt
ORDER BY customer, col_name;', @cols, @cols); 

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @query;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/450286)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║   col    ║ customer ║ 2015_1 ║ 2015_2 ║ 2015_3 ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ No_Trans ║        1 ║     30 ║     20 ║     10 ║
║ points   ║        1 ║     10 ║      5 ║     15 ║
║ spend    ║        1 ║    400 ║    150 ║    500 ║
║ No_Trans ║        2 ║      5 ║        ║        ║
║ points   ║        2 ║      7 ║        ║        ║
║ spend    ║        2 ║    100 ║        ║        ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

If you want `zeros` at missing position you could use `ISNULL/COALESCE`. Be aware that not every datatatype could be replaced by `0 (int)`

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/450289)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

[`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx) is fancy way to replace `%s` with string. It could be easily changed by simple `REPLACE`:

```
 DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
 N'SELECT col1, col2, <placeholder>
   FROM ...
   ...
   PIVOT( MAX(col) IN col2 IN (<placeholder>)
   ...';

 SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '<placeholder', @cols);

 -- for debug
 PRINT @query;
```

How it works:

1. Generate `[year_month]` column in subquery
2. `UNPIVOT` data (columns to row)
3. `PIVOT` result (rows to columns)
4. Wrap it with dynamic-SQL to allow generate columns without knowing `[year_month]` in advance.

Comment: Hi, thank for your help, I would like to order col by specific rows, how can I incorporate order by customer, case col when 'No_trans' then 1, when 'Spend' then 2, when 'points' then 3 else 4 end..

Comment: Hi lad2025, I'm new to dynamic sql and especially pivoting, are you able to go thru the code and explain in simple terms what each section means or is doing? eg. SELECT col_name, customer, %s, what does "%s" do? Or is there some where online you could direct me to read?

Comment: My vote for `FORMATMESSAGE`. Never knew such function exist ;)

Comment: @MotoGP I like it because it is similiar to `printf` in `C` :)